# Problems with OpenSSL on osx

Tags: openssl, osx-yosemite

I tried following these instructions to update OpenSSL on OSX before I started creating certificates.

http://javigon.com/2014/04/09/update-openssl-in-osx/

Something didnt go quite right and now when I run openssl version -a, I get a command not found .

Ive tried installing brew and reinstalling it through there but it says Warning: openssl-1.0.1j already installed. However, I still cant seem to access it.

FYI, my $PATH is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I am a bit of a noob at this so any help appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you haven't finished following the instructions in the link you provide.

Comment: well I completed up to sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/bin/openssl /usr/bin and then tried openssl version -a and it says command not found so I am a bit lost

Comment: Any ideas anyone? Still baffled by this!